# When making a query how do you check if the default value was returned?

Tags: f#

Using the code below:

```
let student =
    query {
        for student in db.Student do
        where (student.StudentID = 1)
        select student
        exactlyOneOrDefault
    }
```

How do you check the value of student, and just what would be the default value if no match in the database was found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database objects come from the database library you're using (either LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework), they're not originated from F# so they're nullable. The value returned by `exactlyOneOrDefault` when there isn't exactly one is `null`.